# PHP gettext doesn't return translated string

Tags: php, gettext

I am trying to setup getText() with PHP

```
$locale = "en_GB";

//if (isset($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
var_dump( file_exists("locale/".$locale."/LC_MESSAGES/".$domain.".mo" ) );
$results = gettext("Velkommen");
if ($results === "Velkommen") {
    echo "Original English was returned. Something wrong\n";
}
echo $results . "\n";
?>
<?= _("Velkommen"); ?>`
```

var_dump returns true, but I get the errormessage saying something went wrong.

Checking locale -a I know that en_GB is present on the server.

I have tried multiple suggestions found on Google.
Tried to change the path in bindtextdomain

Comment: What output do you actually see from `echo $results` in this case? Regarding the "something went wrong" message...you wrote `if ($results === "Velkommen")` - so you're testing if the translated string in $results says "Velkommen"...but then your message says "Original English was returned". Surely if the $results says "Velkommon" then that's _not_ English?? Unless I've misunderstood, the message text seems to contradict the test which the code is carrying out. But you're right, if it's saying that, it presumably didn't translate it _to_ English.

Comment: I get "Velkommen" so you are right, the error message should say Original Danish was returned

Answer (score -1):

This example works for me.

```
print date("d-m-Y H:i:s", date("U"));
$locale = "en_GB";
if (!function_exists("gettext")){ echo "gettext is not installed\n"; } else{ echo "gettext is supported\n"; }
//if (isset($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
if (false === setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale)) {
    throw new LocaleNotSupportedException(sprintf('Locale "%s" is not installed in the system.', $locale));
}
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "locale");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
var_dump( file_exists("locale/".$locale."/LC_MESSAGES/".$domain.".mo" ) );
$results = gettext("Velkommen");
if ($results === "Velkommen") {
    echo "Original Danish was returned. Something wrong\n";
}
echo $results . "\n";
?>
<?= _("Velkommen"); ?>
```

Comment: Please explain how this code solve the issues OP is experiencing

Comment: @DarkBee the OP posted the answer...! But yes I agree a good answer (as per [answer]) would include some context about what the problem was, and how the code in the answer resolves it (with details about what needed to be changed), in order to be more useful to other readers in future.